# Updating Vue CLI Global

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a new Vue.js project using the Vue CLI service, and am running into an error. I have `@vue/cli-service 3.0.0-beta.7` installed (from running `vue -V`). When I try to create a new project, I get this error part of the way through:

```
  Invoking generators...
 ERROR  TypeError: api.injectImports is not a function
TypeError: api.injectImports is not a function
at module.exports (/path/my-project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/generator/router/index.js:2:7)
at module.exports (/path/my-project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/generator/index.js:28:24)
at Generator.plugins.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Generator.js:46:7)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at new Generator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Generator.js:44:13)
at Creator.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Creator.js:137:23)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

This happened trying to create both a Typescript and a Javascript project.

So I tried to update `vue/cli-service`. The latest version is `3.0.0-beta.15`. When I run `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli-service`, it goes to work, and then tells me `up to date`. But if I run `vue -V`, it still says `3.0.0-beta.7`.

If I run `npm i -g @vue/cli-service@3.0.0-beta.15` it appears to install correctly, but running `vue -V` still shows `3.0.0-beta.7`. I also still get the error I mentioned up top when I try to create a new project.

What am I missing?

Edit: To be more clear: I'm assuming that the bug I'm getting from Vue is fixed in the latest version of the CLI package. So what I'm asking here is for insight into the proper method of updating the global Vue CLI package. Following [the instructions here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-global-packages) didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A co-worker helped me out. It's `npm i -g @vue/cli` not `@vue/cli-service`. I'm not sure how I got that mixed up.